# Keyboard shortcuts not working

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts

I usually work on a Mac. I have just gotten a lenovo Windows 7 thinkpad x220 tablet (it's a laptop that can transform into a 'tablet'), then install Windows 8 on it but shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>V</kbd>/<kbd>R</kbd>/<kbd>A</kbd> etc are not working..

I tried deleting my keyboard driver and installing it again via Windows. Did not help.

What can I do?

Comment: Have you tried both Ctrl keys? Also try toggling the Fn key, maybe it's affecting things somehow.

Comment: uhm actually right ctrl key works.. What should i do with the fn key ?

Comment: Does Fn+LCtrl+C work perhaps? Maybe the LCtrl key is broken?

Comment: fn+l ctrl+c does not work. It could be broken but it's a brand new laptop.

Comment: "it's a brand new laptop" - Well, that's no guarantee for it not to break, is it? :) Did it work in Win7 (if you remember)? Can you also check in another OS - say by booting from a Linux LiveCD/USB)?

Comment: Have you tried the Lenovo [Thinkvantage](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?LegacyDocID=MIGR-73695) tool to assure you have the proper Windows 8 drivers for the X220? Would also assure all other drivers are as up to date as possible.